# What is 'blending' for a turbine blade?

Tags: jet-engine, turbine, aircraft-maintenance

What is the process of 'blending' that is used as part of jet engine maintenance?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blending is the process of filing and polishing damaged sections off of the turbine blade. This prevents further damage and extends the life of the engine without having to replace parts, making it a very economical solution. There is a limit however, as modifying the turbine blades leads to a small cost in efficiency that can build up over time.

[image: Blended vs unblended blade]

Comment: Doesn't working on a blade affect the balance of the rest of the turbine? How is that restored? Must the entire assembly be re-balanced post-blending?

Comment: @curious_cat Good question. I think I'll post that as a separate question.

Comment: Howcome it's called 'blending'?

Comment: In that image, I'd assume that the post-blending blade is the one on the right. However, the one on the left actually looks like it's got more material on it. I wonder if it was a damaged blade that had additional metal welded on, then the blending is the grinding/polishing process necessary to get it back to the proper shape and to balance it with the rest of the fan.